# How to Use OpenTelemetry to Send Query Result as a Metric? (No Agent)

Tags: java, sql, database, open-telemetry

I have a database regarding an app, and a query that selects specific information from it.

I would like to convert the information derived from the query result to a custom metric for OpenTelemetry to export. How do I do that?

I found this link while researching the issue: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/trace/semantic_conventions/database.md

Do I have to use java.sql to get the query result first, and then export it as a metric through OpenTelemetry? If so, how do I achieve the latter?

Can I send the query directly through OpenTelemetry (with something similar to the "db.statement" attribute, I'm guessing) so that it will execute the query for me and register the result as a custom metric to export, instead? If so, how?

I do not have a OneAgent installed, nor do I wish to, if possible.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You are asking about `metric` and then you link `trace` specification. `metric` != `trace`, they are 2 different entities.

Comment: You are right; I still don't have full knowledge of the framework, and I fear I have mixed them up.
From what I understand, OpenTelemetry metrics can be exported to application monitors. I would like to make a custom metric (the query result) that I can export through OpenTelemetry.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.